# Submit AJAX form through console (developer tools)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, debugging, developer-tools

I'm debugging server errors and need to submit the form manually through console (bypassing front-end validations). The problem is, the usual approach `$('form').submit()` fails because it tries to submit my AJAX form **synchronously**. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use the normal form with its JavaScript and change the data posted to the server.

For Firefox e.g. there is an Add-on "[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)" which allows you to debug and change all requests before they are send.
(These Add-ons are available for all other browsers, too, just ask google.)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out, I just thought there may be a way to do it with jquery?

Comment: Maybe this will be possible, but you will have to show the code to us and the solution won't be general.